# Converting one bit to an ascci value

Tags: java, hex

So I'm reading bytes as a fileinputstream and then taking one bit to hexidecimal. How to I convert the value then to the ascii value if there is one. All I've seen on how to do this is from pure Binary?

Comment: You mean one `byte`, right?

Comment: show the example code that you use. Are you sure you convert one bit into hexadecimal?